# Can a background worker exit by itself when it runs into an unhandled exception, but the service continues to run?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool, backgroundworker

**Setup**:
C#, .Net 4.5.2. Windows service; fires up 30 background workers that will dequeue items from an external queue and connect to DB to run some logic. Service is 32-bit running on a 64-bit Win 2012 server.

**Problem**:
For some reason, if there is a SQL Exception, all threads stop responding one by one, but the service shows that its still running under the services.msc.

**Details**: 
The DB is known to go offline every once in a while, and anytime it happens, our service stops working. In most cases, we don't have a choice but to restart it manually.
Current code base is not using the OnCompleted events to catch an exception and there is no additional logic to reset the threads or something similar along these lines.

**What I can't understand**:
I can't wrap my head around that when an exception takes place, does the background worker continues to run, so in this case, SQL exception, it waits for the default connection timeout, 15 or 30 seconds, and then it forgets about the exception that just happened, and moves on to the next item?

For some reason, it seems to me that when an exception happens, that thread is pretty much useless, and once all the threads deal with this exception, they don't really do anything behind the scenes, but for some reason, the service itself shows that its still running, and doesn't exit out.

**Debugging on local**:
When I'm debugging on local (VS), after a few minutes, all threads do seem to exist with code 0 and the service exists out as well, but I'm unable to see this behaviour on the server.

**Question**: 
Is it possible that all foreground threads die/aren't doing anything but the service itself stays alive? Can you guys recommend a good way to reset all the threads if a known but unhandled exception occurs?

**Code**:

**Service.cs**

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                {
                    stt = new STF.STT();
                    stt.STP(check, i);
                    alBots.Add(stt);
                    count++;                    
                    check = false;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Start Thread

```
public Boolean STP(bool check, int ctr)
        {
            threadCheck = check;
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                bwAppprocessor = new BackgroundWorker();
                bwAppprocessor.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                bwAppprocessor.RunWorkerCompleted += BwAppprocessor_RunWorkerCompleted;
                bwAppprocessor.DoWork += BwAppprocessor_DoWork;

                tmrPollChk = new System.Timers.Timer();
                tmrPollChk.Elapsed += TmrPollChk_Elapsed;
                tmrPollChk.Interval = Properties.Settings.Default.ThreadPollTimer;

                tmrPollChk.Start();
                bwAppprocessor.RunWorkerAsync();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

DoWork

```
        private void BwAppprocessor_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DoWorkProcesses();

        }
```

Actual work

```
 void DoWorkProcesses()
        {
            try
            {

                //Business logic-connect to DB
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
              //It logs error here
            }
        }

ONComplete
```

```
    private void BwAppprocessor_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Not much going on here; no error handling :(
            //or checking for e.Error :(
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //Useless
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is very hard to suggest an improvement without seeing your code. We don't need the details, just the relevant parts. Maybe you can provide a [mcve], that'd be awesome.

Comment: BTW: Usage of `BackgroundWorker` in a Service seems a little bit odd (at least to me). Has there been a particular reason for that choice of architecture?

Comment: Its an existing and an older app, so not much info on why this was chosen. I've been looking at TPL, but before I can rewrite, I need to fix this first. I added some basic code logic in my question as well, hope it helps to paint a bit more clearer picture.

Comment: Not sure if you will be happy with TPL in dotnet 4.5.2. Didn't keep track of when specific features were added. If you are forced to stay on 4.5.2, consider that constraint in your research.

Comment: Uh wow. This looks not at all production-ready to me. You are more than justified to give it a complete make-over.

Answer (score 0):

In your case [SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Control_Manager) started your service, and it will remain in "running" state after OnStart method exit. You have to sign to SCM somewhere that your job finished. Therefore call [Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) after your **last** BackgroundWorker completed.